# How can I position an image to the right of my conditions?

Tags: floats

[image]

Instead of being beneath the conditions, how do I place it to the right?

My conditions code :

```
 where:
    \begin{conditions}
    V  &  Volume of cone (cm^{3}) \\ 
    SA  &  Surface area of cone (cm^{2})  \\
    r  & Radius of cone (cm)\\
    l  & Slant height of cone (cm) \\
     
    \end{conditions}
```

Comment: There are many ways to do that. Either with a table or minipages, for example. You should try one of these.

Comment: Please upvote/accept answers to your previous questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\vfill
\begin{minipage}{0.3\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\end{minipage}\hfil
\begin{minipage}{0.55\linewidth}
where:
    \begin{align*}
    V  &=  Volume of cone (cm^{3}) \\ 
    SA  &=  Surface area of cone (cm^{2})  \\
    r  &= Radius of cone (cm)\\
    l  &= Slant height of cone (cm)
    \end{align*}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```