# How can I vertically raise an image with wrapfig code?

Tags: minipage

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
%Paragraph jumps and indentation
\setlength{\parindent}{1.27cm}
%Border
\usepackage[left=1in, right=1in, top=1in, bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}



\vfill
\noindent
\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
$r$ = 3 cm\\
$h$ = 15 cm\\
$l$ (not used) = 17 cm\\
$V$ (listed on packaging) = 125 ml\\
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.4\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{ice cream oreo.png}
        \caption{Figure 1: Dimensions of Igloo Cookies \& Cream cone ice cream}
\end{minipage}\hfil
\end{document}
```

[image: My code says error: caption outside float]

Comment: Did you try with `\raisebox`?

Comment: wrapfig needs to be placed before the paragraph that needs to wrap around it, in your example (which we can not run as it is incomplete) there is no following text. Place it before your list, also you specified the width of the cutout as `1.7\textwidth` which can not possibly work, you need something more like .4 not 1.7

Comment: @DhruvNair why not use the same solution https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/623064/how-can-i-position-an-image-to-the-right-of-my-conditions -- suggest to accept and upvote the previous solutions provided -- this is the norm for this site to show appreciation for time and effort spent

Comment: @jsbibra thank you for letting me know, I was not aware of this.

Comment: I have edited my code and it seems like it works right now. The only problem is my caption is weirdly spaced, and it says an error with the float. Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\setlength{\parindent}{1.27cm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
    \begin{align*}
                              r & = \qty{3}{\centi\metre}\\
                              h & = \qty{15}{\centi\metre}\\
            l \text{(not used)} & = \qty{17}{\centi\metre}\\
V \text{(listed on packaging)}  & = \qty{125}{\milli\litre}
    \end{align*}
\end{minipage}%
    \hfill%
\begin{minipage}{0.4\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}  %{ice cream oreo.png}
    \captionof{figure}{Dimensions of Igloo Cookies \& Cream cone ice cream}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum**
or with use `adjustbox` package:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\setlength{\parindent}{1.27cm}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}% it load graphicx package too
\usepackage[skip=1ex, font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[11]

\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.7\linewidth}
    \begin{align*}
                               r & = \qty{3}{\centi\metre}\\
                               h & = \qty{15}{\centi\metre}\\
            l \text{ (not used)} & = \qty{17}{\centi\metre}\\
V \text{ (listed on packaging)}  & = \qty{125}{\milli\litre}
    \end{align*}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=t]{example-image-duck}  %{ice cream oreo.png}
    \captionof{figure}{Dimensions of Igloo Cookies \& Cream cone ice cream}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
\lipsum[12]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This shows how to use paracol to achieve the desired result.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
%Paragraph jumps and indentation
\setlength{\parindent}{1.27cm}
%Border
\usepackage[left=1in, right=1in, top=1in, bottom=1in, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{paracol}

\begin{document}

\setcolumnwidth{0.5\linewidth}
\begin{paracol}{2}
\null\vfil\noindent% center text vertically
$r$ = 3 cm\\
$h$ = 15 cm\\
$l$ (not used) = 17 cm\\
$V$ (listed on packaging) = 125 ml\\
\switchcolumn
\begin{figure}[h]
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
    \caption{Dimensions of Igloo Cookies \& Cream cone ice cream}
\end{figure}
\end{paracol}
\hrule% show bottom of area used

\end{document}
```